# Polymer keypress event handler not being called

Tags: javascript, keypress, polymer

Can't figure out why in the following polymer I am unable to get the keypressHandler function to be called.  What am I doing wrong?  (I tried putting the on-keypress attribute on the span element itself, but still no cigar.) The rest of the functionality works as expected.

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">

<polymer-element name="psq-posscell" attributes="isposs nVal"  on-tap="{{toggle}}" on-keypress="{{keypressHandler}}" >
  <template>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../bower_components/polymer-flex-layout/polymer-flex-layout.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="psq.css" />
    <span class="flexbox align-center justify-center toggle" >{{isposs ? nVal : ' '}}</span>
    <style>
        .toggle {
            float:left; 
            border:1px solid white;
            text-align:center;  
            line-height:2;
            background-color:#f2f2f2;      
        }

        .toggle:hover {
            background-color:#0d2f5a;
            color:white; 
          }

    </style>

  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer('psq-posscell', {
      isposs: true,
      toggle: function() {
        this.isposs = !this.isposs;
        console.log("toggle called");
      },
      ispossChanged: function() {
        console.log("ispossChanged called");
      },
      keypressHandler: function(event, detail, sender) { 
        console.log("key pressed");
      },
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Answer (score 6):

When you press a key, the system has to know where to send the event. This is why there is a concept of `focus`. For your element to receive keys it must be focused.

You can make it focus-able by setting `tabIndex`, e.g.

`ready: function() { this.tabIndex = 0; }`

Now you can cause your element to be focused by calling the `focus()` method on the element (`this.focus()`), or by tabbing to it or clicking on it.

Once your element is focused, it should receive key presses.